# how to replace audio track in mkv file (on Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, ogg, webm, mkv

I have

- a mkv file with webm video and ogg audio
- an ogg audio file

I want to replace the audio in the mkv file with the audio from the ogg file.
How can I do that on Ubuntu 11.10 with programs available from default repositories?

The resulting file may also have another format (e.g. avi), but I would prefer mkv.
Btw. doesn't ffmpeg have an mkv muxer? My test with param *-f mkv* resulted in error *Requested output format 'mkv' is not a suitable output format*

Comment: @casperOne How exactly is this question off topic?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Matroska file format (mkv) is specified with `-f matroska`option. It should be supported by ffmpeg (version 0.7.3) in Ubuntu 11.10. Use `ffmpeg -formats` for a list of supported file formats.

To merge specific streams (audio or video) from several files use `-i` option for each input and `-map input_index[:stream_index]`. For example, the following command merges the first stream of the first input with the second input and keeps the codecs:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i input_audio.ogg -map 0:0 -map 1 \
    -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mkv
```

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the cmd I needed. And sry for posting a "wrong" question, wasn't aware about that.

Comment: It's not so much the wrong question (it is a fine question) as it is the wrong site. This should have been asked on superuser.com

Comment: VLC stops opening an `mkv` file after this command (Ubuntu 14.04).